# How can I set a default profile for the Firefox driver in Selenium Webdriver 3?

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, geckodriver, firefox-profile

I can't set a default profile for Firefox in Selenium Webdriver 3 because there is no such constructor in the `FirefoxDriver` class.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.ProfilesIni;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class SeleniumStartTest {
    @Test
    public void seleniumFirefox() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\FirefoxDriver\\geckodriver.exe");
        ProfilesIni profileIni = new ProfilesIni();
        FirefoxProfile profile = profileIni.getProfile("default");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
    }
}
```

Compile error in Java code:
[Java Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3DMF.jpg)

Maven `pom.xml` dependencies:
[Selenium 3.14.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYrw4.jpg)

Firefox version:
[Firefox version 62.0.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdWld.jpg)

Comment: You should create a FirefoxOptions object to set the profile. `FirefoxOptions fo = new FirefoxOptions(); fo.setProfile(profile); WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(fo);`

Comment: Ok, it works. The project runs without compile or runtime exceptions, but Firefox has been opening for 2 minutes, why so much time? Maybe there is any other solution. Because without this profile settings, the project starts in 10 sec.

Comment: @VladyslavKuhivchak : Ideally it should start in 10 sec. What all are you loading in profile ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using *Selenium 3.14.0* as per the [FirefoxDriver](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxDriver.html) Class the valid constructors are:

- `FirefoxDriver()`
- `FirefoxDriver(FirefoxOptions options)`
- `FirefoxDriver(GeckoDriverService service)`
- `FirefoxDriver(GeckoDriverService service, FirefoxOptions options)`
- `FirefoxDriver(XpiDriverService service)`
- `FirefoxDriver(XpiDriverService service, FirefoxOptions options)`

So, as per your code attempts the following is not a valid option to invoke `FirefoxDriver()`

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

### Solution

To invoke invoke `FirefoxDriver()` with the **default profile** you need to use the `setProfile(profile)` method to set the *FirefoxProfile* through an instance of `FirefoxOptions()` and you can use the following code block:

- Code Block:

  ```
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions;
  import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile;
  import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.ProfilesIni;
  import org.testng.annotations.Test;

  public class A_FirefoxProfile {

        @Test
        public void seleniumFirefox() {
          System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:/Utility/BrowserDrivers/geckodriver.exe");
          ProfilesIni profileIni = new ProfilesIni();
          FirefoxProfile profile = profileIni.getProfile("default");
          FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
          options.setProfile(profile);
          WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
          driver.get("http://www.google.com");
          System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
        }

  }
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  [RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.14.2
  1537775040906   geckodriver INFO    geckodriver 0.20.1
  1537775040923   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:28133
  Sep 24, 2018 1:14:30 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
  INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
  Google
  PASSED: seleniumFirefox

  ===============================================
      Default test
      Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
  ===============================================


  ===============================================
  Default suite
  Total tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
  ===============================================
  ```

Comment: I get a null from ´profileIni.getProfile("default");´

Answer (score 1):

move your setup to `@BeforeClass`

I'm using this setup, works just fine:

```
@BeforeClass
public static void setUpClass() {
    FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
    ProfilesIni allProfiles = new ProfilesIni();         
    FirefoxProfile selenium_profile = allProfiles.getProfile("selenium_profile");
    options.setProfile(selenium_profile);
    options.setBinary("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\pburgr\\Desktop\\geckodriver-v0.20.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
    driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();}
```

just change paths and profile designation.

Comment: ´new ProfilesIni()´ seems to have an empty HashMap. Also logically not clear, how this should know from Firefox Profiles

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you pass the profile folder, not a profile name like ´default´

```
String profileFolder = "..."; // Location according to firefox profile settings 
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions(); 
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile(profileFolder);
options.setProfile(profile);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
```

As already mentionned in comments, the setup takes about 30 seconds.