# Selenium Tests take several minutes to start when loading a profile

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, geckodriver, firefox-profile

I am just trying to figure out if anyone else has seen their Selenium tests run significantly slower (takes 2+ minutes to start) when they load a profile into the FirefoxDriver as shown in:
[Selenium a default profile for the Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52464598/selenium-a-default-profile-for-the-firefox)

The question originator of the above post mentioned this issue in a comment, but never updated whether he fixed this slowness issue.

At some point my tests stopped running all together and I started getting the error

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.io.Exception: unexpected end of stream on Connection.
```

If I remove the profile option from the FirefoxDriver call then the test runs within 5 seconds of selecting "RUN" but the test fails because the default profile Selenium uses does not have the certificates I need to access my site.

Anyone else in the same boat or know how to fix this? How do you adjust how much information is saved within a profile?

- Firefox Version: 60.3.0
- Selenium Version: 3.14.0
- GeckoDriver Version: 0.23.0
- OS: Linux Redhat 6
- Eclipse Version: Neon

---

Code:

```
WebDriver browser;
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/path/to/geckodriver.exe");
ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();
FirefoxProfile ffprofile = profile.get("SeleniumUser");
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions().setProfile(ffprofile);
browser = new FirefoxDriver(options); // takes a long time and eventually fails here
browser.get("site.url");
```

If you take out the {options} parameter from the new FirefoxDriver() call the test will start in about 5 seconds.
Keeping the options causes the error "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.io.Exception: unexpected end of stream on Connection" as stated above.

Comment: are you using Selenium Grid?  please show relevant code

Comment: @CoreyGoldberg Yes, the version of Selenium I use is considered to be Grid (2 I think).  I updated the question to include the code

Answer (score 2):

When you initiate the process to load a new/existing `FirefoxProfile` through *GeckoDriver* the underlying framework consisting of:

- The *Driver* (Selenium binding)
- The *Server* (GeckoDriver)
- The *Client* (Firefox Browser)

Needs to initialize and intercommunicate with different internal modules.

You can find a detailed discussion on how to access a `FirefoxProfile` through *GeckoDriver* with in [Cannot resolve constructor FirefoxDriver(org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49683355/cannot-resolve-constructor-firefoxdriverorg-openqa-selenium-firefox-firefoxprof/49686604#49686604)

Additionally the saved:

- Bookmarks
- Password
- User Preferences

are also loaded when an existing `FirefoxProfile` loads. Hence some added time is required.

You can find a detailed discussion in [webdriver.FirefoxProfile(): Is it possible to use a profile without making a copy of it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49356081/webdriver-firefoxprofile-is-it-possible-to-use-a-profile-without-making-a-cop/49358656#49358656)