# Error: Can't find profile directory. console.warn: SearchSettings: "get: No settings file exists, new profile?" using GeckoDriver Firefox and Selenium

Tags: selenium, firefox, selenium-firefoxdriver, gecko, firefox-profile

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 7.3.0
1609754675168   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:123456
1609754675873   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe" "--marionette" "-foreground" "-no-remote" "-profile" "C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\rust_mozprofileomKd1k"
Can't find symbol 'eglSwapBuffersWithDamageEXT'.
Can't find symbol 'eglSetDamageRegionKHR'.
JavaScript error: resource://gre/modules/XULStore.jsm, line 66: Error: Can't find profile directory.
console.warn: SearchSettings: "get: No settings file exists, new profile?" (new Error("", "(unknown module)"))
1609754679973   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 53339
1609754680041   Marionette  WARN    TLS certificate errors will be ignored for this session
Jan 04, 2021 3:34:40 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
FirefoxDriver: firefox on WINDOWS (f53578b1-71b7-46a7-85ef-8bfd18ba1bc2)
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipSecureFile$1 (file:/C:/Users/S%20K%M/.m2/repository/org/apache/poi/poi-ooxml/3.17/poi-ooxml-3.17.jar) to field java.io.FilterInputStream.in
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipSecureFile$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
JavaScript warning: https://resulticks.team/Scripts/Commonfunction.js, line 147: unreachable code after return statement
JavaScript warning: https://resulticks.team/Scripts/Commonfunction.js, line 147: unreachable code after return statement
1609754783815   Marionette  INFO    Stopped listening on port 53339

###!!! [Child][RunMessage] Error: Channel closing: too late to send/recv, messages will be lost

log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (freemarker.cache).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

Given implicit wait time

```
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(80, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Same code working in chrome..

For firefox below code used for launch:

private synchronized ThreadLocal createFirefoxDriver()

```
{ // FF Profile
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/driver/geckodriver.exe");
        ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();
        FirefoxProfile testprofile = profile.getProfile("Selenium");
        FirefoxOptions foptions = new FirefoxOptions();
        foptions.setProfile(testprofile);
        DesiredCapabilities dc = new DesiredCapabilities();
        dc.setCapability("marionatte", false);
        foptions.merge(dc);
        driver.set(new FirefoxDriver(foptions));

        return driver;
}
```

Thanks @DebanjanB..Still my issue not resolved.. After running script by using profile

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 7.3.0
1609825445685   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:2634
1609825469323   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe" "--marionette" "-foreground" "-no-remote" "-profile" "C:\\Users\\SKMAST~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\rust_mozprofileVF0L8V"
Can't find symbol 'eglSwapBuffersWithDamageEXT'.
Can't find symbol 'eglSetDamageRegionKHR'.
1609825472726   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 64263
1609825473031   Marionette  WARN    TLS certificate errors will be ignored for this session
Jan 05, 2021 11:14:33 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
JavaScript warning: https://weburl/Scripts/Commonfunction.js, line 147: unreachable code after return statement
1609825500246   Marionette  INFO    Stopped listening on port 64263
JavaScript error: https://weburl/DashBoard/Index, line 2521: ReferenceError: LoadingPanelDisplay is not defined

###!!! [Child][RunMessage] Error: Channel closing: too late to send/recv, messages will be lost

log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (freemarker.cache).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

My Issue is

1. In my application after login, trying to find element  without loading page element found message and capturing screenshot. in another case after login, I have to click element without loading page element clicked message showing after few seconds page loaded. but same code working in chrome.

Answer (score 1):

This error message...

```
Can't find symbol 'eglSwapBuffersWithDamageEXT'.
Can't find symbol 'eglSetDamageRegionKHR'.
JavaScript error: resource://gre/modules/XULStore.jsm, line 66: Error: Can't find profile directory.
console.warn: SearchSettings: "get: No settings file exists, new profile?" (new Error("", "(unknown module)"))
```

...implies that the [firefox-profile](/questions/tagged/firefox-profile) by the name *Selenium* doesn't exist.

---

### Solution

Before you try to access the `firefox-profile` by the name *Selenium* you have to create it first following the steps mentioned in [Creating a new Firefox profile on Windows](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Creating_a_new_Firefox_profile_on_Windows)

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [console.warn: SearchSettings: "get: No settings file exists, new profile?" (new Error("", "(unknown module)")) using Selenium and Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65711412/7429447)
- [Cannot resolve constructor FirefoxDriver(org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49683355/cannot-resolve-constructor-firefoxdriverorg-openqa-selenium-firefox-firefoxprof/49686604#49686604)
- [How to use both the Firefox Profile and Firefox options with Selenium in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63477601/how-to-use-both-the-firefox-profile-and-firefox-options-with-selenium-in-java/63481613#63481613)
- [Selenium Tests take several minutes to start when loading a profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53886741/selenium-tests-take-several-minutes-to-start-when-loading-a-profile/54072337#54072337)