# i'm tring to automate target.com in selenium using java

Tags: java, selenium, maven, automation

[image]  1.error in line 3
i can't access registration btn (I tried using by id ,XPath,name and selector but dont work! )

```
@Test
public void registration() throws InterruptedException {
    mydriver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[2]/nav/a[7]/span[4]")).click(); // pass
    Thread.sleep(2000);// just for test
    mydriver.findElement(By.id("accountNav-signIn")).click(); // fail

    // mydriver.findElement(By.name("usernamecreateaccount")).sendKeys("test@gmail.com");
    // mydriver.findElement(By.name("firstnamecreateaccount")).sendKeys("mohammed");
    // mydriver.findElement(By.name("lastnamecreateaccount")).sendKeys("mobark");
    // mydriver.findElement(By.name("passwordcreateaccount")).sendKeys("Pass@1234");
    // WebElement submit_btn  =  mydriver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"createAccount\"]"));
}
```

Comment: Obvious thing but have you confirmed that document.getElementById('...') returns the element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type `about:profiles` in the URL bar of firefox and check if the
default profile exists at the location, If it doesn't exist just
create the one and provide the default or desired location.

Click on `Create a new profile` -> `Continue` --> `Enter the profile name` -> `click Done`

```
Try to access the profile created with the below lines of code

    ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();
    FirefoxProfile ffProfile = profile.getProfile("ffProfile");
    
    FirefoxOptions option = new FirefoxOptions();
    option.setProfile(ffProfile);
            
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(option);
            
    driver.get("https://www.target.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

The menu appears only when hovering over sign in element.
Try hovering and clicking on the sign-in menu and then moving to sign-in `li` and clicking it with `Actions`.
Like this:

```
Actions action = new Actions(mydriver);
WebElement webElement = mydriver.findElement(By.xpath("//nav[@id='headerMain']//a[@id='account']"));
WebElement webElement1 = mydriver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@id='accountNav-signIn']"));
action.moveToElement(webElement).click(webElement).moveToElement(webElement1).click(webElement1).build().perform();
```

**UPD**
As about

> Can't find profile directory. console.warn: SearchSettings: "get: No settings file exists, new profile?

error see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65561051/error-cant-find-profile-directory-console-warn-searchsettings-get-no-sett) and other answers [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=Can%27t+find+profile+directory.+console.warn%3A+SearchSettings%3A+%22get%3A+No+settings+file+exists%2C+new+profile%3F&oq=Can%27t+find+profile+directory.+console.warn%3A+SearchSettings%3A+%22get%3A+No+settings+file+exists%2C+new+profile%3F&aqs=chrome..69i57.711j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)
First of all validate your browser profile as mentioned there.

Comment: `The menu appears only when hovering over sign in element.` - without HTML or Page URL how did you get to know it's an hovering issue

Comment: He mentioned he is trying to automate target.com

Comment: the same error 
`JavaScript error: resource://gre/modules/XULStore.jsm, line 66: Error: Can't find profile directory.
console.warn: SearchSettings: "get: No settings file exists, new profile?`

Comment: @M.Mobark you did not mention this error before. I'll try to see what is it caused by.

Comment: @Prophet : okay I didn't read the heading.

Comment: @M.Mobark see updated answer. Looks like your problem is much before any actual code flow line as I referenced you