# "get: No settings file exists, new profile?" (new NotFoundError("Could not open the file at /tmp using Selenium GeckoDriver on remote Ubuntu ligthsail

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox, geckodriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I'm struggling with the Firefox webdriver implementation on a Lightsail instance since few days.

I'm trying to make run this simple code:

```
opts = FirefoxOptions()
opts.add_argument('-headless')

driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=opts)

print(f"Driver creation: {time.perf_counter() - ts}")
ts = time.perf_counter()


driver.install_addon(os.path.abspath('metamask-10.2.2-an+fx.xpi'), temporary=True)

print(f"Add on installation: {time.perf_counter() - ts}")
ts = time.perf_counter()

driver.get('https://www.youtube.com')

print(f"Go to Youtube: {time.perf_counter() - ts}")

driver.close()
```

On my local machine, I got for result:

```
Driver creation: 1.2246361820007223
Add on installation: 0.9261693749995175
Go to Youtube: 1.8188569550002285
```

And the geckodriver.log:

```
1644664439885   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:48035
1644664439888   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "/usr/bin/firefox" "--marionette" "-headless" "--remote-debugging-port" "55337" "-no-remote" "-profile" "/tmp/rust_mozprofileyCDIKp"
*** You are running in headless mode.
1644664440148   Marionette  INFO    Marionette enabled
[GFX1-]: RenderCompositorSWGL failed mapping default framebuffer, no dt
console.warn: SearchSettings: "get: No settings file exists, new profile?" (new NotFoundError("Could not open the file at /tmp/rust_mozprofileyCDIKp/search.json.mozlz4", (void 0)))
DevTools listening on ws://localhost:55337/devtools/browser/1817941e-57a7-42f0-92dc-cc6c9aabaf0b
1644664441030   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 43901
1644664441101   RemoteAgent WARN    TLS certificate errors will be ignored for this session
JavaScript warning: moz-extension://4ba69c0a-421f-4439-bc86-32f0a1c5a733/background-6.js, line 46: asm.js type error: expecting argument type declaration for 'e' of the form 'arg = arg|0' or 'arg = +arg' or 'arg = fround(arg)'
JavaScript warning: moz-extension://4ba69c0a-421f-4439-bc86-32f0a1c5a733/ui-3.js, line 7: unreachable code after return statement
JavaScript warning: moz-extension://4ba69c0a-421f-4439-bc86-32f0a1c5a733/ui-3.js, line 7: unreachable code after return statement
JavaScript warning: moz-extension://4ba69c0a-421f-4439-bc86-32f0a1c5a733/ui-3.js, line 7: unreachable code after return statement
JavaScript warning: moz-extension://4ba69c0a-421f-4439-bc86-32f0a1c5a733/ui-5.js, line 1: unreachable code after return statement
JavaScript warning: moz-extension://4ba69c0a-421f-4439-bc86-32f0a1c5a733/ui-5.js, line 1: unreachable code after return statement
JavaScript warning: moz-extension://4ba69c0a-421f-4439-bc86-32f0a1c5a733/ui-5.js, line 1: unreachable code after return statement
1644664442980   Marionette  WARN    Ignoring event 'pageshow' because document has an invalid readyState of 'uninitialized'.
```

I would like to have approximatly the same result on my remote Lightsail instance.
I tried a lot of solution I found on google, but nothing worked, so this is what I did:

- Delete instance -> Create a new one (Ubuntu 20.04LTS)
- Make server routine:

  - sudo apt-get update
  - sudo apt-get upgrade
- Install GeckoDriver:

  - wget https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.30.0/geckodriver-v0.30.0-linux64.tar.gz
  - tar -xvzf geckodriver*
  - chmod +x geckodriver
  - sudo mv geckodriver /usr/local/bin/
- Install Firefox:

  - sudo apt install firefox
- Install python3-pip and the requirements for selenium.

The result after launching a test:

```
Driver creation: 6.041947366000045
Add on installation: 11.09006381100005
==> Server block after few minutes
```

and the geckodriver.log:

```
1644660948039   geckodriver     INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:41557
1644660948538   mozrunner::runner       INFO    Running command: "/usr/bin/firefox" "--marionette" "-headless" 
"--disable-dev-shm-usage" "--no-sandbox" "--window-size=1920,1080" "--ignore-certificate-errors" "--allow-runni
ng-insecure-content" "--proxy-server=\'direct://\'" "--proxy-bypass-list=*" "--start-maximized" "--disable-gpu"
 "--disable-setuid-sandbox" "--remote-debugging-port" "58861" "-no-remote" "-profile" "/tmp/rust_mozprofilejTQJ
s8"
*** You are running in headless mode.
[GFX1-]: glxtest: libGL.so.1 missing
[GFX1-]: glxtest: libEGL missing
1644660949544   Marionette      INFO    Marionette enabled
[GFX1-]: RenderCompositorSWGL failed mapping default framebuffer, no dt
console.warn: SearchSettings: "get: No settings file exists, new profile?" (new NotFoundError("Could not open t
he file at /tmp/rust_mozprofilejTQJs8/search.json.mozlz4", (void 0)))
DevTools listening on ws://localhost:58861/devtools/browser/73d9a07f-26e3-45aa-b118-79158a25d2dd
1644660953547   Marionette      INFO    Listening on port 46187
1644660953617   RemoteAgent     WARN    TLS certificate errors will be ignored for this session
```

The difference I found from the local geckodriver.log, is about libGL and libEgl, so I install:

- apt install libgl1-mesa-glx
- apt install libegl-dev

After testing:

```
Driver creation: 5.604287772000134
Add on installation: 52.37673208100023
==> Block after few minutes
```

The geckodriver.log:

```
1644671693878   geckodriver     INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:38405
1644671694374   mozrunner::runner       INFO    Running command: "/usr/bin/firefox" "--marionette" "-headless" 
"--remote-debugging-port" "35887" "-no-remote" "-profile" "/tmp/rust_mozprofileNhzPGd"
*** You are running in headless mode.
[GFX1-]: glxtest: Unable to open a connection to the X server
[GFX1-]: glxtest: libEGL missing
1644671695500   Marionette      INFO    Marionette enabled
[GFX1-]: RenderCompositorSWGL failed mapping default framebuffer, no dt
console.warn: SearchSettings: "get: No settings file exists, new profile?" (new NotFoundError("Could not open t
he file at /tmp/rust_mozprofileNhzPGd/search.json.mozlz4", (void 0)))
DevTools listening on ws://localhost:35887/devtools/browser/b99cd6dd-92a1-4c98-aec0-8c2dfb6c29b1
1644671699397   Marionette      INFO    Listening on port 39313
1644671699537   RemoteAgent     WARN    TLS certificate errors will be ignored for this session
JavaScript warning: moz-extension://2c7aa371-d63f-4896-8c5f-dab9902639ff/background-6.js, line 46: asm.js type 
error: expecting argument type declaration for 'e' of the form 'arg = arg|0' or 'arg = +arg' or 'arg = fround(a
rg)'
```

I really don't know how to make it work on my Lightsail instance.
I don't know what I can add to help someone to find a solution, maybe the versionning on my remote:

- firefox -v: Mozilla Firefox 96.0

I tried a lot of other solutions found on the web, but as I don't understand what's the problem, everything else does nothing more.
Thanks advance.

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
1644671694374   mozrunner::runner       INFO    Running command: "/usr/bin/firefox" "--marionette" "-headless" "--remote-debugging-port" "35887" "-no-remote" "-profile" "/tmp/rust_mozprofileNhzPGd"
*** You are running in headless mode.
[GFX1-]: glxtest: Unable to open a connection to the X server
[GFX1-]: glxtest: libEGL missing
1644671695500   Marionette      INFO    Marionette enabled
[GFX1-]: RenderCompositorSWGL failed mapping default framebuffer, no dt
console.warn: SearchSettings: "get: No settings file exists, new profile?" (new NotFoundError("Could not open the file at /tmp/rust_mozprofileNhzPGd/search.json.mozlz4", (void 0)))
```

...implies that the [GeckoDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45331403/7429447) instance was unable to initiate/spawn a new *Browsing Context*.

The most probable reason is there is/are dangling/zombie ***rust_mozprofile*** instances clinging within the `/tmp` directory. As a result, though *`/tmp/rust_mozprofileNhzPGd`* was created by [GeckoDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45510453/7429447) but *`/tmp/rust_mozprofileNhzPGd/search.json.mozlz4`* can't be accessed.

---

### Solution

You need to invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully at the end of each execution. Incase the dangling/zombie [GeckoDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47095220/7429447) process still continues to occupy your system memory you need to forcefully kill them.

---

### References

You can find a relevant detailed discussions in:

- [console.warn: SearchSettings: "get: No settings file exists, new profile?" (new Error("", "(unknown module)")) using Selenium and Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65711412/7429447)
- [Error: Can't find profile directory. console.warn: SearchSettings: "get: No settings file exists, new profile?" using GeckoDriver Firefox and Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65561051/7429447)

---

Additionally, you may need to update the [firefox](/questions/tagged/firefox) version to the latest release of ***v97.0***.

[image: firefox97]

Comment: Thx for answer. I don't understand many things: - I code in Python, I did not find a tearDown methods in Selenium. - I don't have any folder that starts with "rust" in my /tmp/ folder. I created a new Lightsail Instance only to try this simple code, and it still doesn't work. I don't know what to do. Also; I have the same error in my local machine but it works well ..

 I'm not able to update firefox too with the command "sudo apt install --only-upgrade firefox" it tell me 96.0 is the newest version.

Comment: Check the links mentioned in the _References_ section you will find discussions about  `tearDown()` method.

Comment: I used your solution with psutils you gave to another question.
It changes nothing, it still doesn't works. I still have the "glxtest: libEGL" error and the "Javascript warning: moz-extnesion" error too.

Comment: [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) version? GeckoDriver version?

Comment: selenium==4.1.0 ///
geckodriver = 0.30.0 : https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.30.0/geckodriver-v0.30.0-linux64.tar.gz