# How to bypass login using cookie in Selenium Java?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I looked at multiple sources on the web. For example, https://www.guru99.com/handling-cookies-selenium-webdriver.html
Nothing works as they describe. After adding cookies with `driver.manage().addCookie(ck)`, you still stay on the login page.
Could you, please provide, at least one **working** example on how to bypass the login screen to speed up the test execution suite in WebDriver Java?

Comment: I think you want to set Selenium to use a profile that is already logged-in/remembered.  It's going to depend on the site's authorization, but some will use sessions cookies which are tied to a profile.

Comment: @pcalkins Could you provide a code sample? Thanks

Comment: There's a post here about Chromedriver: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14480717/load-chrome-profile-using-selenium-webdriver-using-java  And Firefox here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52464598/how-can-i-set-a-default-profile-for-the-firefox-driver-in-selenium-webdriver-3  I don't think you can set one for IE/Edge.

Comment: @pcalkins, I could not find anything about adding cookies to ChromeOptions to bypass login in the links you provided. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @Vladimir, the point is: 1. create manualy new browser profile 2. open browser manualy and perform login 3. load driver with the new profile.

Comment: @pburgr 1. I created a new profile manually in Chrome Version 83.0.4103.116.2. Logged in to the page. 3. Added the new profile to the script. Still stay on the login page. String chromeProfilePath = "C:\\Users\\vladi\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Profile 1";
     WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
     ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
     options.addArguments("user-data-dir=" + chromeProfilePath);
  WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver(options);        
  driver.get("http://demo.guru99.com/test/cookie/selenium_aut.php");

Comment: I created an avatar Tester for the new profile. But when the script opens the login page I see Not Signed In icon. Is that the correct behavior?

Comment: You have to navigate the driver to http://demo.guru99.com/test/cookie/selenium_cookie.php to check the cookie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I misunderstood the process. The sources I used all copy the same error. Thank you to @pburgr for the hint. The correct process is

1. Login to the site with your username and password to record the cookies into the file.
2. Open login page to get the domain cookies.
3. Add cookies from the file to your request and go to the home page bypassing login process.
   In the code that is available on the web, they go to the login page in step 3 instead of the home page.

Answer (score 0):

as Vladimir said:

```
driver.get("http://demo.guru99.com/test/cookie/selenium_aut.php");
//read cookies from file and add it to browser 
driver.manage().addCookie(cookie);
driver.navigate().refresh();
```