# Selenium driver hanging on OS alert

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using Selenium in Python (3.11) with a Firefox (107) driver.

With the driver I navigate to a page which, after several actions, triggers an OS alert (prompting me to launch a program). When this alert pops up, the driver hangs, and only once it is closed manually does my script continue to run.

I have tried `driver.quit()`, as well as using

```
os.system("taskkill /F /pid " + str(process.ProcessId))
```

with the driver's PID, with no luck.

I have managed to prevent the pop-up from popping up with

```
options.set_preference("security.external_protocol_requires_permission", False)
```

but the code still hangs the same way at the point where the popup *would* have popped up.

I don't care whether the program launches or not, I just need my code to not require human intervention at this key point.

here is a minimal example of what I currently have:

```
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains, Keys
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from seleniumwire import webdriver

options = Options()
options.binary_location = r'C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe'
options.set_preference("security.external_protocol_requires_permission", False)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)

# Go to the page
driver.get(url)

user_field = driver.find_element("id", "UserName")
user_field.send_keys(username)
pass_field = driver.find_element("id", "Password")
pass_field.send_keys(password)
pass_field.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

#this is the point where the pop up appears

reqs = driver.requests

print("Success!")
driver.quit()
```

Comment: For me, there is a halt, but the code continues to execute normally after a few seconds. Is it this delay which you're trying to remove? Or does your program halt indefinitely?

Comment: @Lucan Mine halts indefinitely. I even left it over my lunch break just to be sure.

Comment: What is the dialog (pop-up) that shows after sending your credentials?   Why don't you close the dialog with code?

Comment: The dialogue is almost identical to a screenshot posted in the comments. I don't know how to close it with code, that's the essence of my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some prefs you can try

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference('dom.push.enabled', False)

# or

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference('dom.webnotifications.enabled', False)
profile.set_preference('dom.webnotifications.serviceworker.enabled', False)
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried setting this preference to prevent the particular popup:

```
profile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile', 'typeOfFile')  
# e.g. profile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile', 'application/xml,application/octet-stream')
```

Or have you tried just dismissing the popup:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

....
pass_field.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

#this is the point where the pop up appears
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.alert_is_present).dismiss()
reqs = driver.requests
...
```

Comment: I have not tried either of those, but they lookpromising!

Comment: Let me know how it goes. If not maybe you can provide me with more code so that I can re-create the issue.

Comment: Selenium doesn't recognize that kind of alerts, the `WebDriverWait` won't work here.

Answer (score 1):

check this checkbox manually then open the app for every app associated to the links you use, then it will work normally.

[image]

Comment: HI, I tried this, and either Firefox does not truly remember or it doesn't work.

Comment: To get that to work, you might need to use a profile in Firefox. Selenium is starting with a fresh profile per default. Here I found an answer to load the default profile: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52474787/12914172

Comment: @r000bin how would I extract/export the Firefox profile that contains this checkbox change?

Comment: Here you'll find the profiles and which file contains your change: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profiles-where-firefox-stores-user-data#:~:text=Firefox%20stores%20your%20profile%20folder%20in%20this%20location,folder%20as%20follows%3A%20Click%20the%20Windows%20Start%20button.